# naiveBayes does not give expected probabilities

Tags: r, naive-bayes, computational-statistics, e1071

I do not understand how the naiveBayes method from the e1071 package is calculating probabilities when classes are perfectly separable (more generally in categories where there are only one class present). For example:

```
model = naiveBayes(y~x, data.frame(x=factor(c(0,1,0,1)), y=factor(c(0,1,0,1))))
predict(model, data.frame(x=factor(c(0,1))), type='raw')
# Expected
# 1 0
# 0 1
# Obtained
# 0.999000999 0.000999001
# 0.000999001 0.999000999
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well the expected and obtained results are very similar. Were you expecting them to be exactly the same or were you expecting there to be more uncertainty given the limited data?

Comment: @Hugh I expect what the Naive Bayes formula gives which is 1. The example I showed is minimal, but in more complex cases it sometimes gives more probability to the class with zero examples :( . This happens in the case that the value of X in question has few data, so I exepect the estimation to be poor, but giving more probability to the class that has zero examples is too much I think

Answer (score 2):

Computer does the calculations for you, computers do not operate on real numbers, but approximate them. The results would never be exact, and depending on how exactly the calculations were done and how the numbers were represented (e.g. 32-bit, 64-bit), this would limit the precision of estimates. I highly recommend you read [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) by David Goldberg as a starter. The results you show are nearly ones and nearly zeros, so nothing seems wrong about them.

Answer (score 1):

Providing an answer to this old question in case someone else stumbles here late as I did. It seems like the `e1071` package does not compute the posterior probabilities correctly, or perhaps it uses some sort of non-standard calculation.

I happened to notice this when I was experimenting with the Laplace smoothing constant.

A relatively new package `naivebayes` seems to work as expected:

```
> library(naivebayes)
> model = naive_bayes(y~x, data.frame(x=factor(c(0,1,0,1)), y=factor(c(0,1,0,1))))
> predict(model, data.frame(x=factor(c(0,1))), type='prob')
     0 1
[1,] 1 0
[2,] 0 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect. When I repeated the calculations on my machine, the results are as in OP. Most likely, R rounded the values for you when printing them. Alternatively, because of using different compiler, or different versions of the packages or dependencies, the results were slightly different. However if you increased the precision of printing, try `print(..., digits=22)`, unlikely the values would be exact 0 and 1.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you're unfamiliar with the Bayesian method. In the Bayesian view the model doesn't make predictions about the evidence, instead the evidence (data) is certain and it leads us to make predictions about the model.

This is like flipping a biased coin, if you flipped a coin 5 times and got 5 heads you would doubt that it's a fair coin but you wouldn't jump to the conclusion that it lands on head 100% of the time. If you flipped it 100 times and got 100 heads then you would think it's biased but you don't have proof that the chance of heads is $1$, it could be $0.999$ as in your example. You would have to flip an infinite number of coins and never get tails to be 100% sure that a tails cannot occur in the future.

You only have two pieces of data, if we could only make inference from two pieces of data we wouldn't be able to conclude much (like only flipping a coin twice). But in the naive bayes training method the algorithm "observes" these data again and again like flipping a coin repeatedly and observing the same results. This allows its predictions to converge. In your case, once the probability reached 0.999000999 it decided that the algorithm had converged sufficiently so it stopped learning. If it was allowed to continue it would get closer and closer to a probability of 1.

Comment: I don't think this is about the philosophy of bayesianism :) . The method as usually stated (e.g. wikipedia) should give 1 in this case:
$P(C=0 | X=0) = P(X=0 | C=0) P(C=0)/P(X=0) = 1 * 0.5/0.5 = 1$


and I do not know why it does otherwise.

Comment: @Blunder in that example C is the model parameter and X is the evidence, correct? You're looking at C=0 but you ignored that C can be other values between 0 and 1 so the P(X=0) term is not 0.5

Comment: $P(X=0)$ is the a priori distribution of the evidence which by default is chosen by the method as the empirical probabilities. In this case $2/4 = 0.5$.

Comment: @Blunder you don't choose a distribution for the evidence, you choose a distribution for the model. The probability of the evidence is the sum of the probability of the evidence over all models. See the wiki example for finding p(evidence) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Training

Comment: I am too late, but @Bunder is right. This is nothing about priors/posteriors, as these already have a fixed rule of population proportioning, and when we have events that do not occur at all, we need 0 probability estimations. The reasoning is actually about rounding of R, not about Bayesian beliefs!!

Comment: I agree with other comments, in this case the probabilities are everywhere zeros and ones, multiplying and dividing them cannot lead to anything else than zeros and ones. @Bunder already provided the by-hand calculations.